# Xcode Scheme: Can't Select Build Configuration

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I'm so confused about how schemes interact with build configurations right now. As far as I understand, there are 5 main scheme actions: Run, Test, Profile, Analyze, and Archive. For each of these scheme action you can set a build configuration, as in the below images (and don't forget to scroll way down in a moment to see the rest of the question):

[image: run]
[image: test]
[image: profile]
[image: analyze]
[image: debug]

However, here's the puzzling thing. When you hit cmd-B in Xcode it presumably uses the setup from that side-tab in the scheme editor called "Build," which have I net yet pasted, but will now:

[image]

Yet here of all places THERE IS NO WAY TO SELECT A BUILD CONFIGURATION! How can I tell cmd-B to use Debug, Release, etc...? It seems that there's no way to do this, so how does it decide what to use for the build?

Comment: A great question - not sure either of the answers explain how you switch command-B from debug to release.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your screenshots above...

If you do "Build for Running" (shift-command-R), you'll build a Release version of your app.

If you do "Build for Testing" (shift-command-U), you'll build a Debug version of your app.

If you do "Build for Profiling" (shift-command-I), you'll build a Release version of your app.

If you do "Build for Archiving", you'll build a Release version of your app.

If you want to change the version that gets built (Release to Debug or vice versa), you can make that change in the scheme editor.

Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: But what happens when you just do Product - Build, ie Command-B??

Answer (score 1):

The Build "tab" should be visually different because it is not an action like Run or Archive.

In each action you choose the build configuration, but what targets will Xcode build for such action? That's what you specify in Build tab.

For instance, you may have a QuarkExperiment target that you don't want to build when you perform the Archive action, to speed the build up.  You just uncheck the corresponding checkbox.

Also, there are two global options (parallel build and dependencies discovery) that are used for every action.

Comment: So this is actually really terrible UI from Apple because they've combined two completely different things into one list. Most of them are actions, but one is "setting up targets for this scheme"